# Transforming a data frame into a line array

Tags: python, dataframe

I used that to transform a data frame formed of just one column:

```
data = data_Y.values
```

However, I'm not happy with the results for the reason that I wanted all the data in a line, and instead I'm getting all the results on different lines. Do you have any idea how either transform:

[[1],[2]] into [1,2]

or directly getting a line vector from my dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

```
A = np.array([[1],[2]])
B=A.flatten()
assert(np.all(B==np.array([1,2])))
```